# passing varibles to another function in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Im creating a website with some animations that will be played when the user scrolls past a certain point on the page. I have got this to work but in the jQuery code only way i could get it to work was with repeated code, Shown Below.

Is there anyway i can create a function that takes two parameters for box number and the class name, and call that 4 times and just pass specific box number and class name to it? cheers for the help

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $(".box1").each(function() {
    var pos = $(this).offset().top;
    var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (pos < winTop + 600) {
      $(this).addClass("slideone");
    }
  });

  $(".box2").each(function() {
    var pos = $(this).offset().top;
    var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (pos < winTop + 600) {
      $(this).addClass("slidetwo");
    }
  });

  $(".box3").each(function() {
    var pos = $(this).offset().top;
    var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (pos < winTop + 600) {
      $(this).addClass("slidethree");
    }
  });

  $(".box4").each(function() {
    var pos = $(this).offset().top;
    var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (pos < winTop + 600) {
      $(this).addClass("slidefour");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.box1,
.box2,
.box3,
.box4,
{
  opacity: 0;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.slideone,
.slidetwo,
.slidethree,
.slidefour {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: slideone;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideone;
}

.slidetwo {
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

.slidethree {
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

.slidefour {
  animation-delay: 0.9s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.9s;
}

@keyframes slideone {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(70%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideone {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(70%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can DRY this up by using a common class on all the `.boxN` elements, and putting a `data` attribute on those elements to denote the class which should be added, something like this:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() { 
  $(".box").each(function() {
    var $box = $(this);
    if ($box.offset().top < $(window).scrollTop() + 600) {
      $box.addClass($box.data('class'));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="box" data-class="slideone">One</div>
<div class="box" data-class="slidetwo">Two</div>
<div class="box" data-class="slidethree">Three</div>
```